# mouse stopped working, checked htop, and HOLY WOW my kcore file is 140 petabytes!! (see screen shot)

Tags: mouse, files, ls, file-size, proc

My mouse suddenly stopped working on my Ubuntu plex server v12.04 LTS.  It still works as a remote plex server so I'm not too concerned. But I did try to login locally with it and ran htop to see if I could find out what was going on.  Then I went to the /proc directory and did a `ls -la` and low and behold surrounded by a bunch of "0" byte files and folders the kcore file reads as:

140,737,486,266,368 = 140 petabytes

what's up with this?

[image: screen shot of the ls -la directory listing with this huge file]

Answer (score 2):

This is only about your `/proc` and not about your mouse since you asked about `/proc`

You're off by a thousand, since the size is in bytes. According to [Novell knowledge base](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7004153), the kcore file is all the addressable memory of the kernel. The size correspond to the arcitecture limits and you have a 64 bit linux-system with a 128TiB kcore.

As with most files under /proc/, it's a virtual file and it's not wise to do anything with it.